# Two Piecewise functions in a same plot

Tags: pgfplots

I am both new to LaTex and to tex.StackExchange. I am currently taking a course in Game Theory and I am using Latex to type my class notes. So far, I have been using this website to solve my doubts and problems, but I am now facing a puzzle I can't solve on my own. Basically, I have two piecewise functions and I need to plot them in the same graph. These are the two functions:

[PICTURE NO LONGER DISPLAYED BECAUSE OTHERWISE I CAN'T POST THE PICTURES I NEED DUE TO LACK OF REPUTATION].

I have been trying to plot both of them on the same figure on my own, but I have not been successful. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Actually, these functions are best response correspondences of the matching pennies game, if that helps. Notice also that these functions intersect in {0.5,0.5}. Moreover, I need the names of the axis to be properly specified.

Thank you all in advance for your replies.

Best regards,
Héctor.

**EDIT**: As noted by some kind observers, the functions are not properly defined. This are the functions that I actually want to plot:

[image]

Fortunately, a teacher of mine -the one who actually introduced me to LaTex- has provided some help and I have been able to generate this output:

[image]

Ideally, I would like to get rid of the grey lines, as well as of the top and the right axes and the legend box, but these are minor visual modifications that do not affect the information displayed in it. In any case, I don't even know if these modifications are feasible, but I'll investigate as soon as I have some time.

PS: I would share the code, but I actually don't understand the instructions to do it, sorry.

Again, thank you all in advance for your time.

Best,

Héctor.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! These functions do not intersect as indicated, or we're missing some other information.

Comment: Your function present two Kronecker's pulse, one at 0 and other at 1. Do you mind `\ge` instead `=` in right side of equartions, which gives step functions?

Comment: Thanks, Bernard and Zarko! You are actually right, the functions are not properly defined. I am sorry for the confusion. See the edit in my original post for more info!

Comment: @Héctor, to show code, just indent your code by 4 spaces.

Comment: I know, that this is only maths, but you know that this symbol has a strong history...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot two functions in one graph by using the pgfplots package, an axis environment and two addplot commands, see the corresponding manual.

You should also print the words 'if' and 'otherwise' as usual text (using the \text command) as not a mathematical variables.

Comment: it would be nice if you showed the OP how to set this up.  the manual is rather dense and not always intuitive.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, Mathias! I will re-write all the functions of the document in order to write text with the command \text{}. And let me add that I have already been using that manual, but as said by Ellet, it is way detailed and, thus, too confusing for a noob like me. See the EDIT in the original post for more info!

Answer (score 1):

Because -- at least for me -- the question is not very precise I'll start with a very basic answer, assuming that Zarko's comment is right and you mean Kronecker's pulse functions. Here I also simplify this solution in that way, that one will not be able from the resulting picture to distinguish, if the functions will be relations (because at the step values my solution has both values (0 and 1).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-1.5,
            xmax=2.5,
            xlabel={$s_1, s_2$},
            ylabel={$b_1(s_2), b_2(s_1)$},
            mark=none,  % don't show any marks at the given points
        ]
            \addplot [
                blue,
                very thick,
            ] coordinates {
                (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0)
                (0,0)
                (0,1)
                (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},1)
            };
            \addplot [
                red,
            ] coordinates {
                (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0)
                (1,0)
                (1,1)
                (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},1)
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

We will be very helpfull, to improve the code, when you edit your question and are more precise. Maybe you draw a rough sketch in a drawing program or on a piece of paper and scan it.

From your question I don't see where the two functions should intersect each other; especially not at (0.5,0.5).

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful comment and your time. By now, though, I have already solved the issue I had.